# Disable the subjective warning for ELL, like for ELU

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

English Language Learners has the "Your question appears to be subjective and is likely to be closed" filter, which I triggered with [Is "Can I help you" a suitable expression for offering help to a stranger?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/676/54) .

By contrast, the filter is disabled on English Language & Usage.

The filter should be disabled for ELL, because the filter can't distinguish between [use and mention](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/435/1420), and mention of words like "you" is legitimate on this Stack Exchange.

Comment: Congratulations. You have done the site a service through this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). (upvote this answer to remove this question from the unanswered questions list).